# How Angular app will know that DB tables data/state is changed by some other app and then need to refresh its data at component side

Tags: angular, oracle, desktop-application, angular2-changedetection

I have situation in my own development scenario and I need a suggestion what could be the best solution for this scenario.

Scenario: I have one desktop application in which I have integrated Angular application. Oracle Database get updated by desktop app and Angular app too in multiple scenarios.

Suppose in Angular app, I'm displaying one table where from table1 records are shown with pagination. In same case if some other user updated that same oracle database table, how angular will know to update its component's rendered table with newer data.

### Possible Solution that I'm thinking of:

1. Sending some event from desktop application to angular and then Angular will update its component with new data. But using this approach I will introduce tightly coupled architecture case.
2. Use producer-consumer solution like (RabbitMQ or Reddis) and on this third server desktop app will update some flag which will be read by Angular app and then angular app will refresh its components table with new data. Using this approach I will  be implementing loosely coupled architecture case. Here there will be no direct dependency with desktop app to refresh its data.

Please suggest me which approach usually I should follow or suggest me if you have any better approach on for this scenario.

Let me know if you need more details, we can connect or discuss here.

//Amit

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to do it is to have an Api that connect to the database (if it's not already the case).

Then the angular application connect with web-socket to the api and when the data change in the database the API send an event to the front to update the data.

You can optimize of course the event by adding where does the angular application need to look for the new data, or send directly the new data if you know how to manage it in the app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @angularity13 ! I will look into your suggestions.